# Setting SSO with SFDC for a REACT app hosted in Heroku

Tags: heroku, single-sign-on, saml, sfdc

Im having tough time getting a good understanding of how to setup SSO for our app. We're developing a web app that has a Flask-Python backend with a React frontend and its hosted on Heroku. We need to setup SSO to SFDC as the app needs to fetch the users list of opportunities in SFDC upon a successful SSO. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction. I've setup a connected app in SFDC but not sure if we should use SAML or OAuth for the SSO to SFDC.

Many thanks.
​​​​​​​-Sol

Comment: Turns out that what I needed was to utilize the User-Agent OAuth flow for authentication (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm). I was then able to access Salesforce data as each individual user via REST APIs.

Comment: SSO is when the external web app logs a person into Salesforce, and from there they continue in the Salesforce interface. For our implementation we wanted to display data from Salesforce and so we were just looking to leverage the REST API using a connected app. User-Agent Oauth flow allowed us to fetch an access token and use that token to access SFDC data.